# Programmatically override boot function of service providers

Tags: laravel-5

I'm building a RESTful API with Laravel 5.8 that would **ONLY** return JSON responses so I want it to be truly stateless
So for the sake of speed and performance I removed a couple of things including `Sessions`, `Cookies`, Blade and the `ViewServiceProvider`

I also had to override `MailServiceProvider`, `NotificationServiceProvider`

That's all fine and good, but whenever I install a new package, I can't take advantage of the `auto discovery` and have to either publish or manually override the `ServiceProvider`'s `boot`method of that package because it tries to `loadViewsFrom` a non existing directory (yes I removed the entire `resources` directory)

#### Example

`laravel/passport`

I have to ignore the package discover in `composer.json`

```
"dont-discover": [
    "laravel/passport"
]
```

And have to copy paste code from the `ServiceProvider` and remove anything that has to do with views and cookies

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Console;
use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider as BaseProvider;

class PassportServiceProvider extends BaseProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->registerMigrations();

            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../database/migrations' => database_path('migrations'),
            ], 'passport-migrations');

            $this->commands([
                Console\InstallCommand::class,
                Console\ClientCommand::class,
                Console\KeysCommand::class,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this to every package that I install is tedious.
is there a way to programmatically override the `boot` function of Service Providers?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to help you but have you considered to start the project with [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)? Is a stripped version of laravel targeting API applications.

Comment: @dparoli yes but lumen also includes views so it doesn't really solve the problem